# Lost data with Indy10 and iDTCPServer and idTCPClient

Tags: delphi, buffer, tcpclient, indy, tcpserver

I have two programs using Delphy 10.3 and Indy 10  idTCPServer and idTCPClient0:

Server side:

- The server sends a data set 1 of TIDBytes regularly using a timer (150 bytes of data)
- The server sends a data set 2 of TIDBytes but only from time to time
- The server sends the data by using TIDServer.Connection.IOHandler.Write(IDBytesArray);

Client side:

- The client receives the TIDBytes with a thread as described in many examples

Problem

- If the server’s timer does sends data with low frequency (1000 millisec) then all works fine, the client receives both data sets (the one from the server’s timer and the other frequently sent).
- BUT if the server’s timer sends data set 1 in high frequency (every 50 millisec) not all data from the second data set can be received (but all data sent by the timer are being received).

Question
 - might this be a buffer issue? Or does the timer overwrite dataset 2 which is already in the buffer but not yet read by the client? I there any way to overcome this situation?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing your actual code on both ends. TCP is a byte stream, `IOHandler.Write()` doesn't delimit data in any way, or prevent concurrency issues when sending in multiple threads. You are responsible for handling all of that in your own code, but it sounds like you are not. Hard to tell without seeing your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Lebeau thank you indeed for responding. I think you mentioned correctly that a timer can send data to a port and it might mess up another timer which also writes at the same time data to the port.
So I reduced the example:

- The Client sends regularly records of  Data1 structure as tidBytes to the server.
- The server responds with an acknowledge.
- The client checks if the acknowledge belongs to the last sent data set. 
  This works fine **as long the client does not send tha packages faster than every 100 millisec**. If sending say aevry 10 millisec then some acknowledges are lost on the client's side.
  If it helps I could share the whole demo project. But may be this is not what stackoverflow is made to. So I add some code below:

There are two data records defined:
-   TData1 is the one which is being sent from the client to the server. 
-   The server sends a TAcknowledgeData1 back to the client as an acknowledge

```
type
  TData1 = record                         // 11 bytes record
   {header:}
    MessageStart  : Array[1..4] of Char;  // 0
    MessageID     : word;                 // 4
   {content:}
    TransactionNo : Integer;              // 6
    TrackerMsgID  : byte;                 // 10
  end;


type
  TAcknowledgeData1 = record              // 14 bytes record
   {Header:}
    MessageStart  : Array[1..4] of Char;  // 0
    MessageID     : Word;                 // 4
   {content:}
    TransactionNo : Integer;              // 6
    EventID       : Integer;              // 10
 end;
```

The client has a timer which regularly sends a Dataset1 to the server calling the procedure SendData1:

```
procedure TForm1.TimerClientTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendData1(TransactionNr);
  TransactionNr := TransactionNr + 1;
end;

procedure TForm1.SendData1 (Transaction: Integer);
var Data1      : TData1;
    Data1Array : TIDBytes;
begin

   {fill the data1 record:}
    Data1.MessageStart := '$MSG';       //4 bytes
    Data1.MessageID    := 1;            //2 bytes
    Data1.TransactionNo:= Transaction;  //4 bytes
    Data1.TrackerMsgID := 1;            //1 byte
   {set the length of idBytes to get the dta 1 record:}
    setLength (Data1Array,11);
   {move data1 record to idBytes array:}
    Move (Data1.MessageStart[1],Data1Array[0],1);
    Move (Data1.MessageStart[2],Data1Array[1],1);
    Move (Data1.MessageStart[3],Data1Array[2],1);
    Move (Data1.MessageStart[4],Data1Array[3],1);
    Move(Data1.MessageID,    Data1Array[4],sizeOf(Word));
    Move(Data1.TransactionNo,Data1Array[6],sizeOf(Integer));
    Move(Data1.TrackerMsgID, Data1Array[10],sizeOf(Byte));
    try
     TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(Data1Array);
     if chkData.checked then MemoClient.Lines.Add('Client sent Data1:'+inttostr(Data1.TransactionNo));
     except
      on E: Exception do
      begin {nothing}
      if chkData.checked then MemoClient.Lines.Add('Exception occured');
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

The client’s worker thread is calling DataReceived as soon as a acknowledge data package arrives from the server:

```
procedure TForm1.TimerClientTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendData1(TransactionNr);
  TransactionNr := TransactionNr + 1;
end;

procedure TForm1.SendData1 (Transaction: Integer);
var Data1      : TData1;
    Data1Array : TIDBytes;
begin

   {fill the data1 record:}
    Data1.MessageStart := '$MSG';       //4 bytes
    Data1.MessageID    := 1;            //2 bytes
    Data1.TransactionNo:= Transaction;  //4 bytes
    Data1.TrackerMsgID := 1;            //1 byte
   {set the length of idBytes to get the dta 1 record:}
    setLength (Data1Array,11);
   {move data1 record to idBytes array:}
    Move (Data1.MessageStart[1],Data1Array[0],1);
    Move (Data1.MessageStart[2],Data1Array[1],1);
    Move (Data1.MessageStart[3],Data1Array[2],1);
    Move (Data1.MessageStart[4],Data1Array[3],1);
    Move(Data1.MessageID,    Data1Array[4],sizeOf(Word));
    Move(Data1.TransactionNo,Data1Array[6],sizeOf(Integer));
    Move(Data1.TrackerMsgID, Data1Array[10],sizeOf(Byte));
    try
     TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(Data1Array);
     if chkData.checked then MemoClient.Lines.Add('Client sent Data1:'+inttostr(Data1.TransactionNo));
     except
      on E: Exception do
      begin {nothing}
      if chkData.checked then MemoClient.Lines.Add('Exception occured');
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

The client’s worker thread is calling DataReceived as soon as a data package arrives from the server:

```
procedure TForm1.Datareceived (Data : TidBytes);
    var
    MsgStart  : array[1..4] of char;
    s         : string;
    id        : word;
    Data1: TData1;
    Data2: TData2;
    Ack  : TAcknowledgeData1;
    AckArray: TidBytes;
begin
 {get the header:}
  s := bytestostring(Data,0,4);
  if s = '' then exit;
  move (Data[4],id,sizeof(word));
  if (s = '$MSG') then
       begin
      if (ID=3) then
          begin
          move(Data[0],Ack.MessageStart,0);
          Ack.MessageID    := id;
          Move (Data[6],Ack.TransactionNo,SizeOf(Word));
          Move (Data[10],Ack.EventID,SizeOf(Integer));
          LastAck := Ack.TransactionNo;
          end;
       end;
end;
```

The Server calls the procedure DataReceved as soon the client sent a Data1 package. The server sends a Acknowledge package back to the client:

```
procedure TForm1.Datareceived (Data : TidBytes);
    var
    MsgStart  : array[1..4] of char;
    s         : string;
    id        : word;
    Data1: TData1;
    Data2: TData2;
    Ack  : TAcknowledgeData1;
    AckArray: TidBytes;
begin
 {get the header:}
  s := bytestostring(Data,0,4);
  if s = '' then exit;
  move (Data[4],id,sizeof(word));
  if (s = '$MSG') then
       begin
      {Server received Data1:}
       if (ID=1) then
          begin
         {get data1:}
          move(Data[0],Data1.MessageStart,0);
          Data1.MessageID    := id;
          move (Data[6],Data1.TransactionNo,sizeOf(Integer));
          move (Data[10],Data1.TrackerMsgID,sizeOf(Byte));
         {send Acknowledge to client}
          Ack.MessageStart := '$MSG';
          Ack.MessageID    := 3;
          Ack.TransactionNo:= Data1.TransactionNo;
          Ack.EventID      := LastEventID;
          LastEventID      := LastEventID + 1;
          SetLength(AckArray,14);
          Move (Ack.MessageStart[1],AckArray[0],1);
          Move (Ack.MessageStart[2],AckArray[1],1);
          Move (Ack.MessageStart[3],AckArray[2],1);
          Move (Ack.MessageStart[4],AckArray[3],1);
          Move (Ack.MessageID,AckArray[4],sizeOf(Word));
          Move (Ack.TransactionNo,AckArray[6],sizeOf(Integer));
          Move (Ack.EventID,AckArray[10],sizeOf(Integer));
            try
            ClientPortIdContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(AckArray);
            except
            end;
          end;
```

Comment: This is not an answer. You should have posted this as an edit to your original question instead.

Comment: Ok I see. I am a novice in stackoverflow writing. I am sorry, I will do it better in the future.